# how to take only maximum date value is there are two date in a week in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe called Data

```
Date          Value    Frequency
06/01/2020     256        A
07/01/2020     235        A
14/01/2020     85         Q
16/01/2020     625        Q
22/01/2020     125        Q
```

here it is observed that 6/01/2020 and 07/01/2020 are in the same week that is monday and tuesday.
Therefore i wanted to take maximum date from week.

my final dataframe should look like this

```
Date          Value  Frequency
07/01/2020     235      A
16/01/2020     625      Q
22/01/2020     125      Q
```

I want the maximum date from the week , like i have showed in my final dataframe example.

I am new to python, And i am searching answer for this which i didnt find till now ,Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for rows with maximum datetime per rows with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), last select rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

print (df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%U'))
0    2020-01
1    2020-01
2    2020-02
3    2020-02
4    2020-03
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

---

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%U'))['Date'].idxmax()]
print (df)
        Date  Value Frequency
1 2020-01-07    235         A
3 2020-01-16    625         Q
4 2020-01-22    125         Q
```

If format of datetimes cannot be changed:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.loc[d.groupby(d.dt.strftime('%Y-%U')).idxmax()]
print (df)
         Date  Value Frequency
1  07/01/2020    235         A
3  16/01/2020    625         Q
4  22/01/2020    125         Q
```